# @EntityListeners in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created this EntityListener:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class AListener {

    private final ARepository aRepository;

    public AListener(ARepository aRepository) {
        this.aRepository = aRepository;
    }


    ...
}
```

that I use here:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AListener.class)
@Table(name = "CAT")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Cat implements Serializable {
..
}
```

but I see this error: `Class 'AListener' should have [public] no-arg constructor`

and in the logs:

```
Exception Description: Error encountered when instantiating the class [class com.poli.listener.AListener].
Internal Exception: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.poli.listener.AListener]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EntityListener` is JPA feature, not Spring ones. You don't need to declare a listener as a `@Component`, because the JPA provider shall instantiate it.

That's what actually happens here:

1. Spring instantiates a `AListener` bean and injects `ARepository` dependency as expected.
2. JPA provider sees that `AListener` is an entity listener and tries to instantiate it. In order to do it needs no-args constructor (remember that JPA provider knows nothing about Spring and its beans)
3. Instantiation fails, because no-args constructor is not found

You can check it by removing the `ARepository` dependency and adding some logging statements inside the constructor.

If you do need some Spring beans inside the listener you can make them accessible as static fields in some utility class.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, and to add to Semyon's helpful answer, there's a similar but IMO more straightforward way to work around it : having the static fields in the Listener itself, and using an autowired init method to set them (instead of a constructor as in spring components).