# How to inject dependencies in an Entity listener?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to perform an action prior to saving an Entity in a Spring boot application. After researching, I've seen that I cannot configure a sequence to automatically populate an Entity field that isn't the primary key.
Thus, I manually created a sequence in my database and I'm trying to add a *pre-save hook* somewhere in my app to fetch the `nextval()` on my sequence and apply its value (after converting it to a String) to my field. I want to do things that way so I don't need to do it in the service side where instances of my Entity are created.

I have identified multiple ways to do that, including AOP and Entity listeners. So far my best guess for an elegant code is to use an Entity listener with a `@PrePersist` method that fetches the next value and apply it to my field.

The main problem I'm facing is I can't manage to inject my repository dependency in my Entity listener (since it's the repository that hosts the `nextval()` function). I have no idea why this is not working, why my dependency is always null while I can read on multiple websites that this implementation is supposed to work (like in [this article](https://solocoding.dev/blog/eng_spring_entity_listener_SpringBoot_SpringDataJpa) for example).

Here's what I have so far (*edited after the first two answers*):

**My repository:**

```java
package my.project.package.spi.jpa.repository;

@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {

    ...

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT nextval('serial_number_sequence')")
    Long getNextSerialNumber();

}
```

**My Entity:**

```java
package my.project.package.spi.jpa.model;

@Entity
@EntityListeners(MyEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "my_table_id", sequenceName = "id_sequence")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "my_table_id", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "serial_number", nullable = false)
    private String serialNumber;

    ...

    public void setSerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    }
}
```

**My Entity listener:**

```java
package my.project.package.spi.jpa.model;

@Component
public class MyEntityListener {

    @Autowired
    private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

    @PrePersist
    private void beforeSave(MyEntity myEntity) {
        String serialNumber = String.format("%012d", myEntityRepository.getNextSerialNumber());
        myEntity.setSerialNumber(serialNumber);
    }

}
```

**My Spring boot application:**

```java
package my.project.package.starter;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "my.project.package.spi.jpa.model" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "my.project.package.spi.jpa.repository" })
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
        springApplication.addListeners(new ApplicationPidFileWriter());
        springApplication.run(args);
    }

}
```

**Most notable Configuration file:**

```java
package my.project.package.starter.configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.project.package", includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, classes =
        DomainService.class))
public class DomainConfiguration {}
```

**The DomainService it refers to:**

```java
package my.project.package.domain.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Inherited
public @interface DomainService {}
```

My project follows the Clean Code architecture and is divided into multiple modules (one per SPI/API, one for the domain and one for the starter).

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? How can I effectively access my repository from my Entity listener?

Answer (score 0):

Lombok needs the field to be final. See here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-injection-lombok

Comment: You're right, see my comment on pleft's answer though.

Comment: I'm commenting here because I lack the reputation to do elsewhere: As soon as you have more than one constructors, you will have to use the @Autowired annotation as far as I know. However I would investigate why you have to provide a no args constructor for a class that should not be instanciated without the repository.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67234687/6527252), there's an instantiation conflict on the Entity listener between Spring and JPA. This answer suggests accessing the bean through a static field located in a Utility class. I don't really like this solution but I'll still give it a try.