# How Spring Boot Application to listen for a CRUD operations

Tags: java, spring-boot, listener

I am just starting with Spring boot Web Applications, and I am in this point now I need to issue notification in the app ecosystem after CRUD Operation in database (I am using MySQL)
How can I set up a listener and based on the operation to create a new notification. From my search, I land on `@EntityListeners(AuditTrailListener.class)` but not sure how to use it, I will be happy to share with me some examples or to redirect me to the right place to see how to set up that kind of listener.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a collection of links which are providing some details about `@EntityListeners` with JPA in Spring Boot webapplications :

- [JPA Entity Lifecycle Events](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events)
- [A gist of a php-coder](https://gist.github.com/php-coder/1391084/be97af0feb19620fe2a6d2e0276d9b4c638069c6)
- [Spring Data JPA Entity Auditing using EntityListeners](https://roytuts.com/spring-data-jpa-entity-auditing-using-entitylisteners/)
- [Spring JPA Auditing in Official Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#jpa.auditing)
- [StackOverflow: How to use an @Autowired @EntityListener](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56225449/390462)
- [StackOverflow: How to inject a dependency into a JPA @EntityListener](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12155632/390462)

I think you'll have common paths to seek the information you need with all that links. And maybe other people will help you more.